# Relating one frame to a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Say there's point in spacetime which would grow to be a sphere solely because of expansion of spacetime with the rate $v.$ means that, that point which had a frame of its own now is a sphere and contains a lot of frames. my question is what is the relations between the point and the sphere. for example if I had the difference of volume over time (which is the volume of the sphere itself) how could I relate the initial frame of the point with all the frames newly added in sphere?

Comment: Unless you're considering some very singular behavior, a *point* will not grow into a sphere. A small volume can grow into a larger volume, and things like the divergence theorem control this. Although there can be a frame at a single point, you can't have a (continuous) frame field everywhere over a sphere, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yes. the matter I am considering is very specific and is in physics but I have difficulty understanding the math. so just for argument sake I explain one thing and won't go in physical details. with expansion of spacetime the coordinates don't simply move. because there's no preferred frame of reference they change in time and won't keep their identity. now I want to know how to relate the frame of the point to the sphere so I can explain the relationship between frames in time affected by expansion. means that I want to move a frame affected by expansion in time.